# google app engine xml file download

Tags: python, google-app-engine, download

I wrote a simple requestHandler for my GAE application that should create an xml text and let the user download it.

```
class ExportHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        r = "<someTag>tagText<someTag>" # sample xml
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write(r)
```

But it shows me an xml file contents on browser. Should I assign headers['Content-Type'] to something else? Or is there any better way to implement that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `Content Type` to `text/xml` or `application/xml`? See this link for a good description of the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272534/what-content-type-value-should-i-send-for-my-xml-sitemap

Comment: I tried both text/xml and application/xml. All of these are just making xml text show up on browser. The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767910/google-app-engine-python-download-file) suggests using text/csv as a content-type. That makes the file downloadable, but the extension isn't xml. But thanks anw.

Comment: And have you messed around with the `Content Disposition` itself? Something like `self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=myfile.xml'`? This should force the `Save As` dialog, I believe.

Comment: Awesome, good to hear! Good luck with everything.